# dynamic model translation in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am planning to build a cakephp application that can be flexibly translated to many languages(web interface and table content are need to be translated). my problem is when a new languages is added to the system , all the table must provide a translation for each field in the form.

here is my database schema.

CREATE TABLE `fields` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#

## Structure for the `languages` table :

#

CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#

## Structure for the `tables` table :

#

CREATE TABLE `tables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#

## Structure for the `translations` table :

#

CREATE TABLE `translations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

#

## Data for the `fields` table  (LIMIT 0,500)

#

INSERT INTO `fields` (`id`, `table_id`, `name`, `language_id`, `label`, `type`, `required`, `properties`) VALUES 
  (1,1,'name',1,'Nombre','text',NULL,NULL),
  (2,1,'name',2,'Name','text',NULL,NULL),
  (3,2,'name',1,'Name','text',NULL,NULL),
  (4,2,'country_id',1,'Country','select',NULL,NULL),
  (5,2,'address',1,'Address','rich',NULL,NULL),
  (6,2,'tel',1,'Telephone','text',NULL,NULL),
  (7,2,'fax',1,'Fax','text',NULL,NULL),
  (8,2,'website',1,'Web site','text',NULL,NULL),
  (9,2,'email',1,'Email','text',NULL,NULL),
  (10,2,'picture',1,'Picture','upload',NULL,NULL),
  (11,2,'to',1,'To country','select',NULL,NULL),
  (12,2,'latlng',1,'Latitude & Longitud','text',NULL,NULL);

COMMIT;

#

## Data for the `languages` table  (LIMIT 0,500)

#

INSERT INTO `languages` (`id`, `name`, `state`, `label`, `default`) VALUES 
  (1,'En',0,'English',NULL),
  (3,'Fr',0,'France',NULL),
  (2,'Es',1,'Espanol',NULL);

COMMIT;

#

## Data for the `tables` table  (LIMIT 0,500)

#

INSERT INTO `tables` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES 
  (1,'countries','Country'),
  (2,'embassies','Embassy');

when i wanna add a new record to the for instance Embassy table then the formhelper need to have many field named "Name" according to the number of languages activated in the language table.

please help .

thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Translate behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1328/Translate)? Find the book "Practical CakePHP Projects". There is a chapter "Translating Stories" there that could be useful for you.

Comment: Yes but it doesnt meet my requirements. in admin i need abilities to add multiple translation to each record. i dont wanna translate each lang one by one.

Comment: Are you familiar with croogo? If not, you could take a look a at the code. It uses a plugin (Translate) to add translations in the admin to the Nodes (the same as you wish to do) and also uses the Translate behavior if I remember right. Also it only uses one table for all translations (i18n), what probably simplifies things a lot.